# commenting callback functions

Tags: javascript, coding-style, documentation, comments

Just curious what's a good way to comment what parameters will be passed to the callback function.

Suppose we have the following code and *incomplete* comments

```
/**
 * an utterly useless function
 *
 * @param {String} an useless string
 * @param {Boolean} an useless boolean
 * @param {Function} ???
 */

function Useless (str, bool, callback) {
  callback(str, bool);
}
```

What's a good way to say callback will be called with str and bool are parameters?

Comment: Callback function passed `str` and `bool`? I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: the issue is how to comment it in a clean way

Comment: And what's wrong with saying the callback will be passed the other two parameters?

Comment: please see the Charlie Rudenstål response. It's how I'm doing it and why I'm unhappy. I find it verbose and was hoping someone has a "{Type} description" styled-pattern that I can use.

Comment: The first example is needlessly verbose, I suspect deliberately so. I'd just say `callback(str, bool)` and add any contextual information necessary. Anything else should go in the main docs, not the param docs.

Comment: i'm a bit skeptical about having a "main" doc, given it's already hard enough to keep inline comments and per-function comments up to date

Comment: callback(str, bool) perhaps would suffice, but I was looking for something (hopefully a convention too) that allows more explanation (type and description) of each callback parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you will just write an invocation of the function with speaking names:

```
/* 
 * @param {String} input: the text
 * @param {Function} callback(output, hasChanged): called after calculation
 */
```

Or, if the parameters need explanation, you can use a multiline description:

```
/* 
 * @param {String} input: the text
 * @param {Function} callback(result, change)
 *         the function that is called after calculation
 *         result {String}: the output of the computation
 *         change {Boolean}: whether a change has occurred
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any conventions for this. I would just use:

```
@param {Function} Called on success with the response (string) as the first param and the status code (int) as the second
```

I am aware it's quite verbose though.

Another option would be doing it like this (similar to how jQuery does it, not in code that I am aware of, but in their documentation)

```
@param {Function} onSuccess(response, statusCode)
```

Here's an example http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
It's different of course since this is an options object and the documentation has a different structure than inline documentation. But look at the callbacks and you will see the similarity.

It's also a much better idea to use callback(response, statusCode) than callback(string, int) for clarity. If you have to choose one that is. Meaning before type.

Comment: ya that's exactly how I'm doing it at the moment and why I'm unhappy

Comment: Updated it with an example that takes it's inspiration from the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to add a comments in javascript; Here is my **recommendation / best practices**.

using `//` is better than `/* */` because then you can use the latter to take out an entire block containing other comments. However, if you want to use an automatic documentation generation tool, you must use comments similar to javaDoc style.

This is an example that would work with YUI DOC (best one) http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/#start

```
/**
* This is a description
* @namespace My.Namespace
* @method myMethodName
* @param {String} str - some string
* @param {Object} obj - some object
* @param {requestCallback} callback - The callback that handles the response.
* @return {bool} some bool
*/
    function SampleFunction (str, obj, callback) {
         var isTrue = callback(str, obj); // do some process and returns true/false.
         return isTrue ;
    }
```

Other params Examples: - http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * an utterly useless function
 *
 * @param {String} an useless string
 * @param {Boolean} an useless boolean
 * @param {(param1:Number, param2:String ...)=>{}} callback
 */

function Useless (str, bool, callback) {
  callback(str, bool);
}
```